# Trying to find all the commas in the list, what is wrong with this?

Tags: python, string, list, methods

```
a = [',', 'hello',',', 'pear']

for i in a:
    d = 0
    c = []
    b = a[d]
    if b == ',':
        c.append(b)
        d += 1
    else:
        d += 1

print c
```

This only seems to return one comma when there are two within the code. How can I fix this?

Comment: please define d and c outside the for loop.

Comment: Tip: Name your variables properly.

Comment: Why do you even want a list of commas? The commas themselves don't let you do anything. Do you want to *remove* the commas from `a`, or find the positions of the commas, or something else like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you reset `d` to zero at the start of every iteration, and clear `c`.

You need to move the initialization code outside the loop.

While doing this, you could simplify the entire loop like so:

```
a = [',', 'hello',',', 'pear']

c = []
for b in a:
    if b == ',':
        c.append(b)

print c
```

Now observe that code like this lends itself very well to being expressed as a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
a = [',', 'hello',',', 'pear']

c = [b for b in a if b == ',']

print c
```

Answer (score 4):

You are reassigning an empty list to `c` every iteration. You can change your logic like this

```
c = []                # Initialized before the loop
for i in a:
    if i[0] == ',':
        c.append(b)
```

The best way to write this, is to use list comprehension, like this

```
c = [item for item in a if item == ","]
```

This particular way of comprehending lists is called as filtering a list.

Comment: `c = list(',' * a.count(','))` might be another solution.

Comment: @Matthias Or simply `[","] * a.count(",")` ;)

Comment: Or `filter(','.__eq__, a)`, if you're looking for variety.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [',', 'hello',',', 'pear']
print len([x for x in a if x == ','])
```

Comment: actually he wants to fix his snippet.

Comment: @yopy My bad! Guess I can leave my response though, since it solves the problem in another way. :)

Comment: yup :) i can understand.